# What is the meaning of いくらもしないうちに from Spice and Wolf?

Tags: grammar

I have been reading Spice and Wolf with relative ease. Alas, I understand everything in the following phrase

> ヤレイと酒が飲めないことは残念だったが、どの道ホロが出ればいくらもしないうちに部外者を追い出して祭りは佳境に入る。

except for (most especially the bolded) "どの道ホロが出れば**いくらもしない**うちに"

How does one go about thinking through this phrase?

Comment: It"s いくらもしないうちに. https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ヤレイと酒が飲めないことは残念だったが、どの道ホロが出ればいくらもしないうちに部外者を追い出して祭りは佳境に入る。 : It was unfortunate that you couldn't drink sake with ヤレイ, but anyway once Horo appears he will chase the outsiders and the matsuri will become more interesting.

いくらもしないうちに is an expression that means "right after, soon".

どの道 is an expression that means "anyway".